# How to validate a end point / URL?

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, java-security

I want to validate a `URL` in `Java`.

I want to check:-

- *If any `password authnication` is required.*
- *If it is `HTTP or HTTPS`.*
- *If it responds in `JSON` or 'XML/RSS'.*

How can I do this in `Spring / Java`?

Comment: you can get the protocol of URL to check if its http or https. For password protected, you will need to ping URL, and look for error 401.